# How to remove a univariate outlier?

Tags: outliers

While solving a Data Science problems I faced a problem of outlier in one of the columns of a dataset and here's the distplot which clearly shows the presence of this outlier.

[image]

Can you guys please give me some solutions to solve this problem ?

I have already tried log transformation but it didn't affected the data too much so, any other solution would be helpful.